# Как сделать чтобы на md экране offset убирался тоесть был только для lg

Tags: bootstrap, адаптивная-верстка, bootstrap4

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>doctype</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:700" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,800" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expland-lg navbar-dark bg-dark  justify-content-center ">
    <ul class="nav justify-content-center ">
      <li class="py-4 px-2"><a style="color:#e0e0e0" href="#" class="nav-link">HOME</a></li>
      <li class="py-4 px-2"><a style="color:#e0e0e0" href="#" class="nav-link">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
      <li class="py-4 px-2"><a href="#" style="color:#e0e0e0" class="nav-link">ABOUT US</a></li>
      <li class="py-4 px-2"><a href="#" style="color:#e0e0e0" class="nav-link">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div id="sas">
    <div class="container-fluid" id="ole">
      <div class="container align-center">



        <div class="row ">

          <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6">
            <h1>OUR STRONG <br>ORGANAISATION</h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipis cing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et. ectetur adig ipis cing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt. <br><button class="btn btn-danger mt-4"
              id="baton">Contact us</button></div>
          <div class="col-xl-5 mt-4"><img id="lo" src="Vedio Icon.png"><img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/u1nrGUQQz74/maxresdefault.jpg " id="lox"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xl-5 col-lg-5">
          <h2>DO YOU KNOW WE CAN PROVIDE FOR YOU? </h2>
          <br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipis cing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et.Lorem ni ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipis cing elit, ed doi eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et.

        </div>
        <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3">
          <img src="settings.png">
          <h3>Managment</h3>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sitea amet, zixf conseit adipi cing elit, seddi do eiusmod btdempor in didunt utlae ore etioe.Lorem ipsum new idolor
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 ml-4">
          <img src="pencil.png">
          <h3>Ui/Ux Design</h3>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sitea amet, zixf conseit adipi cing elit, seddi do eiusmod btdempor in didunt utlae ore etioe.Lorem ipsum new idolor

        </div>
        <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3  offset-md-5">
          <img src="Diamond.png">
          <h3>Logo/branding</h3>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sitea amet, zixf conseit adipi cing elit, seddi do eiusmod btdempor in didunt utlae ore etioe.Lorem ipsum new idolor

        </div>
        <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 ml-4 ">
          <img src="Truck 2.png">
          <h3>Animation</h3>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sitea amet, zixf conseit adipi cing elit, seddi do eiusmod btdempor in didunt utlae ore etioe.Lorem ipsum new idolor

        </div>
      </div>



    </div>

  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Правильноли я верстаю на bootstrap 4 или по другому нужно часть с табличками нужно чтобы на md экране offset пропадал или по другому сверстать.Помогите пожалуйсто